# TempData to redirected page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Can I send tempdata to a redirected page? if yes how? if no, any alternative?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [TempData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.aspx) to persist data from one request to another when using `Redirect()` and `RedirectToAction()`

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711.aspx) explains it all.

If you want your page to display this data then you just need to pass it to your view from your action.

Comment: Sorry @David the link is no longer working, could you please update? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

TempData will persist for two jumps, while ViewData only persists for one. That is the simplest way I can explain it.